# 403 error when receiving Google Calendar API notification

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I have calendar events being created successfully for various GSuite users, then I'd like to set a watch event. I'm able to do that successfully:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = BASE_DIR + 'path_to_json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

delegated_user = credentials.with_subject(user)
delegated_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=delegated_user)


event = {
        'summary': '%s at %s' % (event_name, event_location),
        'description': 'description',
        'location': event_address,
        'extendedProperties': {
            "private": {
                'briefType': event_name,
            }
        },
        'start': {
            'dateTime': event_start_time.astimezone().isoformat(),
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': event_end_time.astimezone().isoformat(),
        }

    }


event = delegated_service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()

watch_body = {
    'id': event['id'],
    'type': 'web_hook',
    'address': 'https://example.com/googleapi'
}

watch = delegated_service.events().watch(calendarId='primary', body=watch_body).execute()
```

I'm not quite sure how to receive the push notification. I've registered/added my domain (per https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push), and when I change the event in Google Calendar I'm getting an API Push notification, but I'm receiving a 403 error:

```
Dec 11 20:58:38 ip-xxx gunicorn[3104]:  - - [11/Dec/2019:20:58:38 +0000] "POST /googleapi HTTP/1.0" 403 1889 "-" "APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)"
```

How do I authenticate in the `view` that process `/googleapi` to be able to actually receive the API notification from Google?

I've tried the following just to try to debug what I'm receiving from Google, but I get nothing besides the 403 error:

```
def GoogleAPIWatchView(request):

    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = BASE_DIR + 'path_to_json'

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

    regex = re.compile('^HTTP_')
    headers = dict((regex.sub('', header), value) for (header, value) 
           in request.META.items() if header.startswith('HTTP_'))

    print(headers)
    print(request)

    return JsonResponse('success', status=200, safe=False)
```

Comment: Are you able to send requests to the end-point directly? (to `GoogleAPIWatchView` view?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this ***`HTTP 403`*** raised because of ***failed verification of CSRF token***. So, use [**`csrf_exempt`**--Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) decorator to **skip the verification process**

```
#views.py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


@csrf_exempt  # This skips csrf validation.
def GoogleAPIWatchView(request):
    ...
    # do something useful
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application is trying to access user data using a service account, this is right and it is intended to do it so, but because you did not granted this rights to do it you are receiving 403 server responses.

To be able to run your application using a service account as you are trying the service account has to have the following rights granted:

**Domain wide delegation authority:**

If the service account does not have delegation authority over the domain the applications using a service account can not access data on behalf of the users of the domain.

To enable it go to [here](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts):

1. Select your project
2. Select your service account or create a new one
3. Click on 'Edit' to edit parameters of the service account
4. Select 'Enable G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation

Your service account now has domain-wide delegation.

Next you'll need to set the scopes of your service account.

**Service account scopes:**

The administrator of the G Suite domain must follow this steps:

1. Go to your G Suite domain [admin console](http://admin.google.com):
2. Select Security from the list of controls
3. Select Advanced settings from the list of options
4. Select Manage API client access in the Authentication section
5. In the Client Name field enter the service account's Client ID. You can find your service account's client ID in the Service accounts page
6. In the One or More API Scopes field enter the list of scopes that your application should be granted access to. In this case: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
7. Authorize

Google Documentation on domain-wide authority delegation and creation of service accounts:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had already completed those steps, the service account has domain-wide delegation and API client access. I'm able to create events and poll users calendars to detect changes using the service account, but I still get the 403 error when receiving the push notifications.

Comment: I've read it more carefully, there was no need to do the previous, because you are not acting on behalf of any user. My bad.

Regarding the thing, does your domain have SSL certificates?

Comment: Yes, I have SSL certificates and it's connecting via HTTPS.

Comment: Guess valid ones: not expired and not self signed?

Comment: I don't believe they're self signed, I use cerbot/Let's Encrypt. I did run a SSL Server Test here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html, and the results were: TLS 1.3 No, TLS 1.2 Yes, TLS 1.1 Yes, TLS 1.0 Yes, SSL 3 No
SSL 2 No, - so I guess that may be the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204133/discussion-between-yuri-and-andrew).

Comment: "The certificate was issued by Let's Encrypt."

Answer (score 1):

As @JPG rightly pointed out, your **api is rejecting non-authorized request** - push notification from Google. And **CSRF** is most probable cause - unsafe operations (POST, PUT, DELETE) require csrf token to be present in request.

Of course, api clients from other domains cannot provide one, as it is mainly designed to protect cross-domain ajax requests from web-pages rather than non-interactive api calls.

As Google API cannot authorize as regular user while accessing view, we need the view to be open to everyone, and to **allow `POST` requests from everyone** we remove `GoogleAPIWatchView` from csrf check.

**It still requires protection though.**

To make sure request was actually made by Google API, wee can check presence / value of some headers Google API adds to requests:

- **X-Goog-Channel-Id** - [Always present in notification messages posted by the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#understanding-the-notification-message-format)
- [User Agent contains **`APIs-Google`** string](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#receiving-notifications)

Note: all these headers can be spoofed by malicious party.
For additional check [you can define custom token while subscribing to watch notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#making-watch-requests). The token is included in the **X-Goog-Channel-Token** HTTP header in every notification message that your application receives for this channel.

```
...
CHANNEL_TOKEN = "mysecrettoken"
watch_body = {
    'id': event['id'],
    'type': 'web_hook',
    'address': 'https://example.com/googleapi',
    'token': CHANNEL_TOKEN
}
...
```

And in the view we can perform necessary checks to make sure request is from Google:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

@csrf_exempt  # This skips csrf validation.
def GoogleAPIWatchView(request):
    # Validate request came from Google
    if not 'APIs-Google' in request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', ''):
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    if not request.META.get('HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_ID'):
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    if not request.META.get('HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_TOKEN') == CHANNEL_TOKEN:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()

    ...
```

---

In case of [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), you also need view available to everyone without authentication. If `SessionAuthentication` is not present in `AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` - we can skip `@csrf_extempt` decorator as csrf check is [not performed](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#csrf-protection) in that case.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def google_push_notification(request):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]  # or empty []
    # check google headers
    ...
```

Comment: personally, I won't recommend using DRF **only for this purpose**